# What's the Chinese Converse of English "Engrish"?

Tags: vocabulary

We all know and love Engrish- hilariously bad English sometimes produced by native Chinese speakers. But is there an equally pat Chinese phrase to describe the converse- the weird, pitiable attempts at correct Chinese made by the benighted 老外? Seems only fair that there would be...

Comment: I have never heard Chinese speakers saying "Engrish". Even phonetically they would never use an 'r' here, as a Japanese or a Korean speaker might would. How pitiable your question is.

Comment: it's more of a generic term to refer to odd English usages by native speakers of various East Asian kangauges (especially Chinese and Japanese)

Comment: @Drunken Master Perhaps "Engulish" is a better term?

Comment: haha "Engulish" is cool too, just not what we use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a sweeping term for that and I don't think the word Engrish is actually a term either.

But here is something might humour you.

伦敦音: London accent. It's actually from a 相声(Chinese Stand-up comedy) piece. Basically means the way of English speaker trying to say Chinese but can not get the rhyme and all the tones right. And to add humour effect, both 伦 and 敦 are pronounced in flat tone.

Comment: works for me - btw "Engrish" is definitely a term, for better or for worse.  Thanks!

Comment: @MasterSparkles Good to know. Although I don't think there's a term for Chinese with foreigner accent, I do know a term the Chinese use to make fun of us speaking English. Chinglish, which my English teacher told us to avoid. Some typical Chinglish is pronouncing C as Say or V as Vay or We as Way.

Comment: yup Engrish==Chinglish. Same thing :)

Comment: @MasterSparkles Here you say Engrish=Chinglish, but above you say Engrish is odd English usages by native speakers of various East Asian languages including Japanese.  I think these are coarsely humorous words and not really respectable.

Comment: I agree... That's why I'm curious whether the Chinese have any similarly uncouth terms to describe our attempts at Chinese, to balance things out :)  I'm not really sure why I should care if such words are "respectable" or not - they're there, and should be thought about and understood ...

Comment: @MasterSparkles So, as you understand it, is Engrish the same as Chinglish, or is it generic of odd usages by all Asians, or certain kinds of Asians?

Comment: I see what you mean - I guess Chinglish is Engrish when used by Chinese people